# Setting a user agent in Selenium

Tags: selenium, firefox

I'm scraping house rental listings with Selenium using Firefox on a Windows 7 box and have run into a captcha on a website where I have three pages to traverse. Some searching tells me that one of the many techniques I'll have to implement in order to avoid detection is to change the user agent for each request.

I have found Python code on stackoverflow posted as recently as five months ago for doing the same sort of thing in Google Chrome using the following user agent string:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36`

But if I go to [https://www.whatsmyua.info/](https://www.whatsmyua.info) from Firefox on my desktop I see the user agent string is:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0`

And if I do the same thing using the Tor browser I get this:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0`

Those two user agent strings don't resemble the Python-style code at all!

Wouldn't putting reference to Windows, AppleWebKit, Chrome and Safari into the user agent string be an obvious tipoff to the bot detector that this is no ordinary browser access?

Comment: Looks like you need to do some research on what a user agent string actually is. Start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: @DMart Got it! Thanks.